# Как можно дезактивировать событие ввода текста в инпут поле?

Tags: jquery, javascript

На страние представлено текстовое поле для ввода символов. 
Как можно дезактивировать ввод следующего символа при определенном значении флага?
Disable input не годится

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@Oleg Ponomarchuk](/users/18030/oleg-ponomarchuk), повесить событие на keyup, которое будет фильтровать ввод при нужном значении флага.